# Replace <body> tag with another tag

Tags: php, html, document-body

I'm trying to use the following code to replace `<body>` tag from page with `<body id="khanqah">`

```
echo str_replace("%body%", "khanqah", "<body id='%body%'>");
```

It does adds `<body id="khanqah">` to the page but the actual `<body>` tag still presents. I mean there are two body tags now, one `<body>` and the other `<body id="khanqah">`

Also the `<body id="khanqah">` tag is adding at the top of page, see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOKR1.jpg (screenshot of page source)

Is there any way I can work around?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really *replacing* anything in the HTML, it's just [`echoing`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) the return value of `str_replace("%body%", "khanqah", "<body id='%body%'>")` which happens to be the string `<body id="khanqah">`.

You can only replace the HTML's [`body` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/body.html#body) with PHP if you are outputting the HTML *with* PHP (changing it before outputting it). PHP works server-side, so once the HTML reaches the client it cannot modify it.

You can use JavaScript, which works client-side, to do this.

---

To change the id of the body dynamically using jQuery (which is the easiest way), you can do

```
$('body').attr('id', 'khanqah');
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide a code or hint to achive this? I'm fine with simple javascript or jQuery, either of them.

Comment: @ImranOmer I've updated my answer. Remember that this changes the id dynamically, so if you see the source code it will look the same, but the browser _is_ aware that the body has now a different id.

Comment: Actually my page HTML has `<body>` tag, I want to replace it to `<body id="khanqah">`

Does your code replace it like this?

Comment: It doesn't replace it, it just gives it the id `khanqah` (which I think is what you want). Look at this example, it changes the body id and then the body gets the styles according to said id http://jsfiddle.net/TEXM9/.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work here.

I'm using the following  variable inside an HTML template;
`{$body_khanqah}`

and then using the following code in PHP file;

 $body_khanqah = '
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(\'body\').attr(\'id\', \'forums\');
    </script>';

It adds that code but doesn't adds `id="khanqah"` to the body tag.

Comment: Hoping to get an anwer about this.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why do you have to do this from inside PHP? Don't you have access to the HTML document and the JavaScript in it? Also, the code should be `$body_khanqah = '<script type="text/javascript">$("body").attr("id", "khanqah");</script>'`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37908/discussion-between-imran-omer-and-campari)